# Android 4.3 BLE connection with Raspbery Pi (Bluez 5.8)

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy

Device1: Nexus 4 Android 4.3 BLE Central (Using BluetoothLeGatt sample app in API 18 SDK as is)
Device2: Raspberry Pi with working BT4.0 USB Dongle, Raspbian Whezzy 20130726. Compiled Bluez 5.8 from the sources.(Since the packaged ver is 4.99 which not officially support BLE yet)
Working as peripheral, I started bluetoothd with "-p alert" (GATT Alert profile).

Test1: Using two raspi (device2 above) I can connect and browse alert gatt service/characteristics on other device using gattool.
Test2: Using iPhone/iPad (free BLE app: LightBlue) as Central I can also connect and browse alert gatt services and characteristics value on the Raspi.

Test3: When connecting using Nexus 4 sample app, (which is unstable), it asking for authorization on both device.Even after I can get rid off the authorization, the hcidump look like they are exchanging SDP info, the service list still not come up on Android sample app.
Test4: Nexus 4 sample app can connect and browse service on Fitbit One and Wahoo HRM.

Using hcidump (on the raspi), I can see different connection initiation:

Test1/2:

```
>HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 19
   LE Connection Complete
      status 0x00 handle 44, role slave
      bdaddr ... (Public)
```

Test3:

```
>HCI Event: Connect Request (0x04) plen 10
   bdaddr ... class 0x5a020c type ACL
```

(Is it Bluetooth classic connection?)

Question:
Is there any way I can make Android BLE connection to create HCI Event: LE Meta Event on Raspi?

Comment: jsut some remark: I found that 4.3 has couple of problems with BT - strangely all went away after factory reset - and also all brand new Android 4.3 devices worked flawlessly.

Comment: Since there's no brand new 4.3 devices around (planning to buy new nexus 7 if they released in my country...could be few weeks away), I'll try to reset nexus 4 to factory image. It was updated OTA to 4.3. Will report the result.

Comment: Okay, I noticed that the version is JWR66V (Factory image is JWR66Y). Check system updates, upgrade it to the current JWR66Y (supposed it the same as factory reset now). The connect initiation is the same, But at least it look like more stable and show some services list. Some improvement at least. Will further check, but thanks anyway.

Comment: the strange thing is that even two Android devices with exactly the same 4.3 kernel bahave differently - the one after reset works - the other one even right after restart (not reset) does not in my case

Comment: Uhm, it still not stable enough (sometimes service don't show up, sometimes doesn't event connect). Will download the factory image tonight.